# Sull'uso del modo di dire "acqua in bocca!"

Tags: word-usage, idioms

Nel Dizionario dei [Modi di Dire Hoepli](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/A/acqua.shtml#6) ho letto che l'esclamazione "acqua in bocca!"

> è un invito a non divulgare una determinata notizia, a mantenere un segreto.

La definizione che ne fa il [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/acqua/) è molto simile. Tuttavia, in *Acqua in bocca! Tutto quello che vorresti dire in italiano... come lo direbbe un italiano!* di Roberto Bortoluzzi (Edizioni Casa delle lingue, Barcellona, 2015), un libriccino molto interessante che ho trovato in biblioteca, ho letto questa spiegazione:

> **Acqua in bocca**
>
> Se abbiamo dell'acqua in bocca, non possiamo parlare. Per estensione significa *non parlare di qualcosa, non dare delle informazioni.* È sottointeso il senso di mancanza di conoscenza: se non sappiamo qualcosa, non possiamo parlare.
>
> **Esempio:**
>
> Il mese prossimo Valentini se ne va dell'azienda, quindi il suo posto di coordinatore rimarrà vuoto. Oh ma io non ti ho detto niente e tu non sai niente, eh? **Acqua in bocca!**

Forse sono io che non capisco bene, ma a me sembra che quest'ultima definizione non sia esattamente la stessa cosa 
di quello spiegato dai dizionari Hoepli e Treccani. Sembra che si possa dire "acqua in bocca!" quando non si può parlare di qualcosa perché non se ne sa niente. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: potresti spiegarmi come e quando (in quali contesti e in quale registro) si usa l'espressione "acqua in bocca!" facendo alcuni esempi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A me risulta che “Acqua in bocca!” sia sempre e solo un invito a mantenere un segreto, adoperata in un registro amichevole. Dal [dizionario Treccani, voce *acqua*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/acqua/)

> 8. Locuzioni fig.: […] *a. in bocca!*, esortazione a non parlare, a mantenere un segreto; […]

L'origine è chiara: se hai acqua in bocca non puoi parlare. Il significato che il tuo libriccino attribuisce alla locuzione è scorretto. Mettere acqua in bocca è una precisa *azione* (seppure figurata) che non avrebbe senso se il soggetto non sapesse nulla dell'argomento. Deve *fingere* di non sapere nulla dell'argomento, che è ben diverso!

La frase precedente, “io non ti ho detto niente e tu non sai niente” è un  comune modo di dire; significa “fa' come se non ne sapessi niente, da parte mia negherei di averti detto qualcosa”.

Il senso globale è: *ti ho rivelato un segreto perché sei mio amico/mia amica, ma non mettermi nei guai spiattellando che te l'ho detto io*.

Answer (score 3):

Nell'esempio che hai indicato, «io non ti ho detto niente, tu non sai niente» è un'espressione iperbolica e figurata, evidentemente "falsa", perché l'informazione (= Valentini se ne va, il suo posto rimane vuoto) è stata data, quindi chi parla "ha detto" e chi ascolta "sa". Può succedere che qualcuno, dopo aver raccontato qualcosa di segreto o riservato, dica così. Aggiungere «acqua in bocca» significa chiedere di mantenere il segreto, di non divulgare la notizia o l'informazione.

Comment: Questo l'avevo già capito. Il mio problema è con la spiegazione generale che ne fa il libro: "È sottointeso il senso di mancanza di conoscenza: se non sappiamo qualcosa, non possiamo parlare."

Comment: A mio parere, la spiegazione non è corretta: di solito «acqua in bocca» si dice a chi sa ma deve far finta di non sapere (quindi "tiene l'acqua in bocca" per riuscire a non parlare).

Comment: Forse il significato della spiegazione del libro è che si deve far finta di non sapere niente. È così?

Comment: @Charo: Sì, il senso è senz'altro questo, che la mancanza di conoscenza è “sottintesa” nella raccomandazione fatta da chi dice “Acqua in bocca!”, non nello stato di cose effettivo. Cioè, chi dice “Acqua in bocca” sta dicendo “Fa' finta di non sapere niente (e di conseguenza non dire niente)”.